# Blender blending mode and opacity not working

Tags: video-sequence-editor, color

The opacity doesn't seem to work when I apply the `Overlay` blending mode to a color strip. It's either 0% or 100%. Is there any way to make the opacity more incremental? All the other strips below use `Alpha Over`. I'm trying to get the opacity to 50%.

[image]

Comment: and why don't you use alpha over? then opacity will work....

Comment: @Chris - I'd like to use Overlay blend mode for the colour strip and not Alpha Over. The effect is different. Do you know how to make the Overlay blend mode work with opacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a known (but unresolved) bug; see the bug reports https://developer.blender.org/T76376 and https://developer.blender.org/T75844.

I can confirm that it is still present in the latest alpha build 3.0.

Comment: Thanks so much for digging into this! Hopefully it will be resolved soon.